# Optimal way to perform a matrix product based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am working with: `x = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(20, N)))` with `N>5000` and `y = np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(20),size=1)`.

I was performing matrix product between each `x` columns and `y` (which is a list of weight with a sum of 1) to end up with an array of `N` elements so I use `x.T.dot(y)`.

Now, I would like to modify my matrix product computation: for each 0 on the current column of X that is computed, we re-weight `y` by not considering the weight that would have been multiplied by 0 and equally spread it between weights that will be multiplied by values different from 0 so the sum of the list is still 1.

Example with smaller structures

`x`

```
       a1   a2   a3
b1     1    5    6
b2     3    0    0
b3     9    7    0
```

and `y = [0.3, 0.5, 0.2]`

Output expected: `[3.6, 5.9, 6]`

Step 1 : No zeros -> simple weighted average `(0.3*1+0.5*3+0.2*9 = 3.6)`

Step 2: `(b2,a2) = 0` so `y` becomes `[0.55, 0, 0.45]` and `0.55*5+0.45*7 = 5.9`

Step 3: `(b2,a3) & (b3,a3) = 0` so `y` becomes `[1, 0, 0]` and the total is 6.

Specificity: The structure of the Data Frame is build such as when there is a 0, the following cells on the same row will be equal to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a new matrix with the same shape as `A` by stacking `y`, adjust it using a mask, then perform element wise multiplication and sum on columns:

```
y= np.array([0.3, 0.5, 0.2])
A = np.array([[1, 5, 6],
       [3, 0, 0],
       [9, 7, 0]])
m = A == 0
new_y = np.repeat(y,A.shape[1]).reshape(A.shape)
new_y = (new_y + (new_y*m).sum(axis=0)/(~m).sum(axis=0))*~m
result = (new_y * A).sum(axis=0)
result
>> array([3.6 5.9 6. ])
```

Comment: Thank you but I would like to work with A as a data frame. Is it possible?

Comment: Of course! All dataframes store their data in numpy arrays. You can access them with `.values` (e.g. `A = df.values`)

Comment: don't we have to declare `new_y` as `np.repeat(y,A.shape[1]).reshape(A.shape)` ?

Comment: indeed, yes. I didn't pay attention as the matrix was squared in your example. I updated the answer.